# CalendarContract slow in Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

Helo,

I've got this code snippet:

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI + "/" +
            Long.toString(from) + "/" +
            Long.toString(to));

    
    String selection = "(" + selection_allcalendars + " (deleted != 1) AND (" + CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY + " = 0))";

    cur = cr.query(uri, mProjection, selection, null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

It queries the Android calendar events for the time between *from* (in milliseconds) and *to* (in milliseconds).

This works really good, when I want to query all events for a day (app runs in 60 milliseconds). It also works fine, when I query the calendar events for a week (app runs in 80 milliseconds).

But why it takes so long time (e. g. 2-4 seconds), when I want to query the events for a month? My app, which I develop hangs...

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how many events present in database and also how many events present for the month? If the database is yours I would recommend to use database index.

Comment: Helo, I'm using the database of Android calendars. In a week there about 60 events, in a months about 250. In the database there must be over 1000 events. What do you mean with database index?

Comment: I mean if the database is yours you can create a database index to make the retrieval fast

Comment: No, the database is not mine. It uses the android database for calendars. Look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract